# Create a block in view.phtml

Tags: magento, view, block, addition, php

I am wanting to add a block in the view.phtml page.

The block will located above the "Description" section when viewing a product. The block will show different automobiles that fit a particular product. So each time I create/edit a product, I can list the automobiles that fit the part, in the General tab of the Product Information screen (Name, Description, Short Description, SKU, ect...)

I have been researching how to get this done, but I am not sure which XML file needs to be edited and so on.

Is there a step by step instruction guide on adding a custom block to the view.phtml file?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be editting the `app/design/frontend/#package#/#theme#/layout/catalog.xml`

In it, you should add the block as a child of the view.phtml block.
You can do this as follows within the `<catalog_product_view>` tag:

In the `<reference name="content">`

Place the block with your type and name in `<block type="catalog/product_view`

You can then call it with $this->getChildHtml('name')

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am going to try this within a few days and see if I can get it to work.

I can't imagine that it would be very difficult to get this done, but I will give it a shot.